# mounting LUKS volume on android 4.4.2, it can't be seen from another apps

Tags: android, mount, loopback

I have problem with mounting LUKS volume 
I use Google Nexus 7 (2012) updated with Android 4.4.2 and unlocked/rooted.
To mount LUKS volume, I use [LUKS Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager&hl=ja), Busybox and Android Terminal Emulator.
To see mounted file system, I use ES file explorer.

I exec the code below on Android terminal emulator

```
$ su
(root) dd if=/dev/urandom of=/sdcard/encvol bs=1000000 count 10
(root) mknod /dev/loop123 b 7 123
(root) losetup /dev/loop123 /sdcard/encvol
(root) lm.cryptsetup -c aes-cbc-plain -s 256 luksFormat /dev/loop123
...(enter password)
(root) lm.cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop123 decvol
...(enter password)
(root) mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/decvol
(root) mkdir /sdcard/decdir
(root) mount -t ext2 /dev/mapper/decvol /sdcard/decdir
(root) df
...
/storage/emulated/legacy/decdir  7.7M  7.7M  7.7M   1024
```

above operates flawlessly... so I can see lost+found directory in the /sdcard/decdir .

```
(root) ls /sdcard/decdir
lost+found
(root) cat > foobar
this is a test
[EOF]
(root) ls
lost+found    foobar
```

but when I see the directory /sdcard/decdir by ES file explorer, then I can't see any file in the /sdcard/decdir.
I tried another file browser, but it was same.
even in the same program, android terminal emulator, when I exit root shell, then it is no file in the decdir.

```
$ ls /sdcard/decdir   # not a root
...(no file)
$ df
...(not mounted)
(root) su  # be root again
(root) ls /sdcard/decdir
lost+found   foobar
```

is there some good ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: My SuperSU Settings tab.]

Seems like you need to disable the "Mount namespace separation" if you want your mounts done in `su` visible to other apps. This may cause security flaws, but if you really need this, enable it and reboot.

Comment: I didn't test your answer, but it would be the correct answer. When I asked the question, I couldn't find the setting application of SuperSU though.

Comment: Explained here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197959/partition-gets-unmounted-automatically-in-android-oreo/200449#200449

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution...!

It was problem of Super SU and multi user environment of android.
in case of Super SU, `su --mount-master` helps mount LUKS volume system widely.
but unfortunately, Super SU's multi user support is still little iffy, so I replaced Super SU to Superuser. 
and it works perfect as I expected.

Super SU : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=ja

Superuser : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser&hl=ja

Comment: Are you using any additional parameters with Superuser? I tried latest version of Superuser and mounts are local just like with SuperSu.

Comment: I don't know precisely about this problem.  at least in my case, solution was replace SuperSU to superuser. I recently found that you shouldn't choose mount place /sdcard/. it seems that mounting on /sdcard/ has potential error. I recommend that mounting on /mnt/foo.